# What is a 0-cell then?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Q** Is a $0$-cell a point or an empty set?

(1) I am a bit confused about how the notion of $n$-cell is used in the context of CW complexes. For example, Hatcher defines an $n$-cell to be $e_\alpha^n := \Phi_\alpha(\operatorname{Int}(D^n))$ where $\Phi_\alpha: D^n \to X$ is a characteristic map. But $\operatorname{Int}(D^0) = \emptyset$, so $e_\alpha^0 = \emptyset$. On the other hand, he says that each point in the $0$-skeleton is regarded as a $0$-cell. Of course, one can simply solve this issue by defining an $n$-cell via the characteristic map only if $n \geq 1$, but I do not see such restriction in Hatcher at least. Perhaps he does this implicitly as there is no characteristic maps anyway when the CW complex equals the 0-skeleton.

(2) But then, there seems to be a notion of $n$-cell which says that it is a topological space homeomorphic to the closed unit $n$-ball. How does that now fit into place? By definition, $e_\alpha^n$ is homeomorphic to the *open* unit $n$-ball.

Can somebody help to clarify this issue?

Comment: A $0$-dimensional ball is a singleton. (both a closed and open ball)

Comment: Hatcher defines the closed $0$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$ as the set of points at distance $\leq 1$, as usual. That is $\{0\}$. We don't need to attach the $0$-skeleton to anything further down in dimension. That $e^0$ is empty is OK. Even if you want to think that the $0$-skeleton got attached to a discrete space, the $e^0$, being empty, are homeomorphisms. So, it is an identification of the boundaries of the $0$-discs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatcher p. xii (Standard Notations):

> $S^n$ : the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ , all points of distance $1$ from the origin.
> $D^n$ : the unit disk or ball in $\mathbb R^n$, all points of distance $≤ 1$ from the origin.
> $∂D^n = S^{n−1}$ : the boundary of the $n$-disk.
> $e^n$ : an $n$-cell, homeomorphic to the open $n$-disk $D^n − ∂D^n$.
> In particular, $D^0$ and $e^0$ consist of a single point since $\mathbb R^0 = \{0\}$.
> But $S^0$ consists of two points since it is $∂D^1$ .

Note that $∂D^n$ is the *topological boundary* of $D^n$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Thus $\operatorname{Int} D^n = D^n \setminus ∂D^n$.

We have $\operatorname{Int} D^0 = D^0 \setminus ∂D^0 = D^0 \setminus S^{-1}$. By definition $S^{-1}$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb R^0 =\{0\}$ having distance $1$ from $0$. There is no such point, so $S^{-1} = \emptyset$.